# Solving for voltage across three series resistor with multiple voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm new to circuits and I cant wrap my head around how to calculate for
voltage across the three resistors along with multiple voltage sources.

I've attached an image of the circuit.

I have to calculate:  VR2 VR3 and VR4

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: do you know the voltage at any of the nodes?

Comment: the voltage sources are the voltages at the nodes. this circuit is part of a bigger circuit that i have compacted down to the part which im confused

Comment: "compacting down" may be the problem. With the circuit shown, since you know the 3 voltages, just calculate the differences.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One easy way to think about this is that you have ***fixed*** voltages at every node. Since the voltage sources cannot change because they are ideal, then every resistor must drop the difference between the voltage sources. (i.e. V3 never interacts with what happens to the deltaV of R2. Therefore deltaV R2 = (V1-V2))[image]

Another way to look at it is to to a quick KCL so you convince yourself that the voltage drop across the resistors is just the difference of the voltage sources at each node.

Comment: ByTor_Hardware - Hi, Please don't advertise in answers here. That promotion wasn't part of the answer, so you risk it being treated as spam (which has significant consequences). To prevent those consequences for you *this time*, I have removed your promotional content. See [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in the [help] for more details. If you are still unsure about what is allowed, you can ask in [Meta]. You can add your link etc. in your user profile. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

You have to apply the superposition theorem which means that you have to turn selectively off: V1, V2, V3

---

Let's calculate VR2 for example as a sum of three addends:

Calculate VR2' under the following conditions: V1 on, V2 off, V3 off

Calculate VR2'' under the following conditions:  V1 off, V2 on, V3 off

Calculate VR2''' under the following conditions:  V1 off, V2 off, V3 on

And finally:  VR2 = VR2' + VR2'' + VR2'''

Comment: but in order to calculate VR2 do i need to use voltage divider formula?

Comment: Why complicate yourself with superposition?

Comment: It's an answer for newbies.

Comment: Using the superposition principle here makes things more complicated than they need to be and misses the question's actual premise - to understand node voltages with the use of a reference node (GND).